# _billing_address value fill automatically _billing_address_2 with the same value

Tags: woocommerce

I need that when a customer fill _billing_adress in Woocommerce... this value will be the same that _billing_address_2. If is possible with any function?

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'replicate_billing_adress', 100, 1);

function replicate_billing_adress($order_id){
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id); //obatin the completed order as object
    $_billing_address_1 = $order->_billing_address_1(); //get the billing email address
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_address_1', $_billing_address_2); //update the company email
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_address_1', $_billing_address_2); //it maybe saved like that, with underscore, ommit if not needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$order->update_meta_data('_billing_address_2', $_billing_address_1);
$order->save_meta_data();
```

Comment: Thank youuuuuu, but it doesn´t work. I don´t know is your code is for add or edit my function.

Comment: No, for updating your billing address 2, make sure the exact key. I guess the key is just for example.

Answer (score 0):

yes it´s just an example but I don´t know if it will be...

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'replicate_billing_adress', 100, 1);

function replicate_billing_adress($order_id){ 
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);  
$_billing_address_1 = $order->_billing_address_1(); 
update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_address_1', $_billing_address_2); /
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_address_1', $_billing_address_2); 
$order->update_meta_data('_billing_address_2', $_billing_address_1);
$order->save_meta_data();
}
```

I don´t understand your code.

Comment: What would you like to do? Do you want to update `$_billing_address_2` information with `$_billing_address_1` after placing the order?

Comment: Yes! I need to do it. The costumer fill the Checkout fill $_billing_address_1. Pay the order. But I need that in wooocomemrce orders windows show $_billing_address_2 with the same information that $_billing_address_1. Is it possible?

Comment: Use this hook `add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'replicate_billing_adress', 10, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'replicate_billing_adress', 10, 1); 
// Update billing address 2
function replicate_billing_adress($order_id){
     $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
     $_billing_address_1 = $order->_billing_address_1();
     $order->update_meta_data('_billing_address_2', $_billing_address_1);
     $order->save_meta_data();
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'display_billing_address_2_in_admin' );

// display the extra data in the order admin panel
function display_billing_address_2_in_admin( $order ){  ?>
    <div class="order_data_column">
        <h4><?php _e( 'Billing address 2', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h4>
        <?php echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Billing Address 2' ) . ':</strong>' . $order->get_meta( '_billing_address_2' ) . '</p>'; ?>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Comment: Show syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: Which line where your place this code `functions.php`?

Comment: in the line 18.

Comment: Updated the code, try now

Comment: Yes!!!! It works!!! Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: Good to hear. Mark it as a useful answer so that others can be benefitted.